What is this Movie about an intelligent house plant?
I am searching for the movie title.  Please help!
Takes place in the USA about the 1980's?
An single man (a writer?) works from his apartment and has a house plant (spider plant i think) that he has placed in front of the tv.  Eventually the plant starts to show signs of intelligence.  I dont remember the man's role in the movie after the plant grows aware of it's surroundings, but eventually the man put the plant on the ledge for some sunshine and a cat knocks it off and the man comes home to find the plant broken on the street below and is devastated.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Someone has submitted an edit to your question title to make it more useful. If you feel they have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

@Renee: please check the answer

This must be an episode of Amazing Stories: The 21-Inch Sun

But where did that first script come from. It turns out that a variegated spider plant is responsible. She (we are assured it's a she and he names her Lucy) actually covers the portable typewriter, and writes scripts. They begin a kind of cottage industry. Unfortunately, he gets in with the TV crowd and leaves the plant on a window sill. She falls and is picked up by a garbage truck.

Here is an image of the plant and the typewriter:

You can see it here: https://archive.org/details/AmazingStories
